# Let events go through a below panel in GWT

Tags: gwt

Suppose the following.

I have a an AbsolutePanel.
On this AbsolutePanel I add a button.
Finally I add another AbsolutePanel on top of all this with the same size as the first AbsolutePanel.

Now when I click on the button the click gets intercepted by the second AbsolutePanel.
Is there a way that I can let the second AbsolutePanel ignore, or give through the event so that the button receives the event ?

```
AbsolutePanel abs1 = new AbsolutePanel();
abs1.setSize("500px", "500px");
 Button button = new Button("abc");
abs1.add(button, 50, 50);
AbsolutePanel abs2 = new AbsolutePanel();
abs2.setSize("500px", "500px");
abs1.add(abs2, 0, 0);
button.addClickHander...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as I can see, reading `AbsolutePanel`'s JavaDoc:

```
An absolute panel positions all of its children absolutely, allowing them to
overlap
```

I think for some reason you feel good 'playing' with absolute css positioning. So, I think under your circumstances if you just apply a `z-index` css value to `button` **higher** than `abs2`'s `z-index`, solve your problem.

I tested personally, and it works, but remember, the button will be 'over' `abs2`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Add a button *after* adding an absolute panel.
2. Instead of adding the second absolute panel, you can insert it just before the button.